# In spark, Can we perform broadcast join on same table size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Read from text file, parse it and then do some basic filtering to get   data1 (6GB)

```
data1.registerTempTable('data1')
```

Read from text file, parse it and then do some basic filtering to get data1 (5.9GB or equivalent to 6GB)

```
data2.registerTempTable('data2')
```

Perform join

```
data_joined = data1.join(broadcast(data2), data1.id == data2.id,"left")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the broadcast joining of large dataframe like you mentioned above with 6GB, as long as you have enough memory to handle the execution and storage in each node, also you need to wait for the time of data transferring through network. If your resource is enough, you can try it and compare the time difference between both case.